# How #define OBJECT_HEADER(derivedClass) facilitates build the Run-Time Typing Information (RTTI) for the derivedClass

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, rtti

Define a `Base` class. In the Base.h file:

```
class Base{

...
};

#define OBJECT_HEADER(derivedClass) \
public:  \
    virtual SharedPtr<Base> _virtualClone() const; \
    SharedPtr<derivedClass> _clone() const; \
    static Base* createInstance (); \
    static const Type& classTypeID (); \
    virtual const Type& type() const;  \
    static void constructType(); \
    static void destructType();
```

The code comment says that OBJECT_HEADER Helps build the Run-Time Typing Information (RTTI) for the given class derivedClass.  This macro is required in the class definition of any class derived from Base or its derivatives.

Thus, in the example usage:

```
class derivedClass: public Base
{
    OBJECT_HEADER(derivedClass)

public:
...

};
```

However, I do not understand how this macro facilitates RTTI and what is the benefit? Moreover, actually do not understand the macro part of the code. why need backslash for each line?

Comment: \ continues the macro to the next line.

Comment: ***I do not understand how this macro facilitates RTTI*** I assume some other macro implements the members declared using this macro.

Comment: The `Base` class is the abstract class and I do not think there is any macro implements there.

Comment: It looks like the implementation would be in derivedClass.

Comment: I found the implementation about the function of `createInstance`:

    `inline SharedPtr<Base> createInstance(const Type* pType) `
   ` { return pType->createInstance(); }`

This implementation is written as a free function in the `Base` header file

Comment: But my another question is: `createInstance` belongs to a string from macro. How can the compiler know it's a separate function from the macro string?

Comment: The compiler never sees the macro. The preprocessor expands the macro in the place that you have it in the code before the file is compiled.